# Extracting values form nested JSON document

Tags: python, regex, json

I have the following JSON structure. I am attempting to extract the following information from the "brow_eventdetails" section.

- ATime
- SBTime
- CTime

My question is is there any easy way to do this without using regular expression. In other words my question is the a nested JSON format that I can extract by some means using python.

```
       {
            "AppName": "undefined",
            "Event": "browser information event",
            "Message": "brow_eventdetails:{\"Message\":\"for https://mysite.myspace.com/display/CORE/mydetails took too long (821 ms : ATime: 5 ms, SBTime: 391 ms, CTime: 425 ms), and exceeded threshold of 5 ms\",\"Title\":\"mydetails My Work Details\",\"Host\":\"nzmyserver.ad.mydomain.com\",\"Page URL\":\"https://nzmyserver.mydomain.com/display/CORE/mydetails\",\"PL\":821,\"ATime\":5,\"SBTime\":391,\"CTime\":425}",
            "Severity": "warn",
            "UserInfo": "General Info"
        }
```

The program that I use is given below.

```
     with open(fname, 'r+') as f:
       json_data = json.load(f)
       message = json_data['Message']
         nt = message.split('ATime')[1].strip().split(':')[1].split(',')[0]
         bt = message.split('SBTime')[1].strip().split(':')[1].split('\s')[0])
         st = message.split('CTime')[1].strip().split(':')[1].split('\s')[0])
         json_data["ATime"] = bt
         json_data["SBTime"] = st
         json_data["CTime"] = nt
        f.seek(0)
        json.dump(json_data,f,ensure_ascii=True)
```

There are some issues with this program.The first one is extracting ATime,SBTime and CTime. These values are repeated.I want to extract just the numeric values, 5, 391 and 425.I don't want ms that follows it.how can I achieve this?

If I were to update the program to use json.loads() as below I get the following error

with open(fname, 'r+') as f:
       json_data = json.load(f)
       message = json_data['Message']
       message_data = json.loads(message)
       f.seek(0)
       json.dump(json_data,f,ensure_ascii=True)

I get

```
ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded
```

Comment: First of all, you do not have a *NESTED* json document, the field is merely a string representation of an unevaluated json string. Fix this first and stop using `strip` or `split`.

Comment: @Anzel - What do you mean by fixing it? and not using string and split?

Comment: the field value of `message` is currently a string. You are dealing with it like string using `strip` and `split`, **DON'T!**.

Comment: @Anzel - What is the alternative?

Comment: both @Tichodroma and I have given you answers as requested. I am not entirely sure why you would have a malformed but double rendered json in the first place. But if you are going to deal with json using Python, parse it as Python object (list, dictionary ... etc.) first.

Comment: You need to discard the `message` string of `'brow_eventdetails:'` as this isn't a valid json string (field name without quotes `""`) so it fails when you do `json.loads`. Discard it first, like I use `replace('brow_eventdetails:', '')`, then the remaining string `{...}` can be parsed by `json.loads`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to parse again the json string of `json_data['message']` then just access the desired values, one way to do it:

```
# since the string value of `message` itself isn't a valid json string
# discard it, and parse it with json again
brow_eventdetails = json.loads(json_data['message'].replace('brow_eventdetails:', ''))

brow_eventdetails['ATime']
Out[6]: 5

brow_eventdetails['SBTime']
Out[7]: 391

brow_eventdetails['CTime']
Out[8]: 425

...
```

Answer (score 1):

Parse this string value using json.loads as you would with every other string that contains JSON.